# Does search suggestion from out of the box of CQ work for AEM 6.0?

Tags: javascript, java, aem

I am trying to use out of the box search functionality from CQ. The search functionality works in CQ 5.6 but not working for AEM 6.0. Can any one tell me the reason why it is not working or am i looking at the wrong place?

Comment: Can you be more specific. Which search suggestion are you mentioning? The `searchfield` xtype or the searchbox in `damadmin` or something else altogether?

Comment: without further information, maybe you need to build an index first. AEM 6 uses Oak instead of Jackrabbit, thus not all lucene indices are pre-configured as they were before.

Comment: search suggestion for cq5 works fine. But the same doesn't work with AEM 6.0. Since AEM 6.0 uses Oak instead of jackrabbit, i want an overview regarding configuration to be made for lucene indices.